# Web Scraping: request not returning complete content of the webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am writing a website scraper that saves all names of cryptocurrency from a table within a website. I wrote a script to get the response of the webpage and then by using the `BeautifulSoup` library to parse the response into an HTML object. The issue is the response is not returning the complete content of the webpage. It displays data from a certain position of the table and skips the data above it.

When I try debugging the code the response object has all the data from the webpage but when I try to print the data it only shows data from a certain point in the page.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(response.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'id': 'currencies-all'})
```

It would be really helpful if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong because I am unable to find out the issue.

Comment: what is r.text? do you mean response.text? : BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

Comment: @Alfie yes it was response. text. I mistakenly put r.text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you are hitting the buffer limit of your IDE's console?

On Spyder, the default is 500 lines and you will only see 500 lines of the sourcecode as a result. Try increasing this limit to see if that solves your issue.

On Spyder (windows), it's Tools > Preferences > IPython Console > Buffer (at the bottom).

I increased my buffer to 4000 and it still wasn't enough to fit the entire page but it did reveal more lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out one thing here. The table rows are nested within the table tag. Therefore, you need to first extract the table body then the table rows.
I use 'lxml' parser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(response.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
results = soup.find('tbody')
curr_symbols = [x.text for x in results.find_all('td',attrs={'class':'text-left col-symbol'})]
print(curr_symbols)
print(len(curr_symbols)) # 1878
```